# Why does meta have both "tags" and "tagging" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've noticed that here on meta there is a [tags](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) tag and also a [tagging](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) tag. Are they standard fare on meta sites or did we just naively create them both? I've tended to use both when asking tag-related questions on meta but is there a distinction I hadn't noticed? And if not should we merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reason. The 'tagging' tags have been renamed to [tags](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags).